# site not responding to float:left and float:right in safari (OK in Firefox and Chrome)

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I have a [site](http://zoparealty.com/about/zopa-vendors/) that is supposed to have a left side column and a right side column- and it does in FF and Chrome, however something isn't quite right in Safari. Any ideas what is causing this issue/why is it only messing up in Safari?

[pastebin - code](http://pastebin.com/Sf6rFSit)

[image: safari]

Comment: At my Safari (5.1.2 OSX 10.6.8) is OK. I took a screenshot with Litmus, and appears all right OK

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: @KevinBoucher sorry for the omission, the code can be found here- http://pastebin.com/Sf6rFSit

Comment: @ArielRamone how odd. i've included a screenshot to show what i'm seeing in safari.

Comment: Are you sure you not having a pre-configured font-size or a zoom not set to 0? You can see my inspecteds screenshot here:

[link](http://i48.tinypic.com/ayqdti.png)
[link](http://i46.tinypic.com/347wneu.jpg)

Comment: Ok in Safari 5.1.7, Win7

Answer (score 0):

I checked your url in safari. it working fine.